# Need to evaluate content in drop-down in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

As stated in the topic I need to evaluate two fields, one from a drop-down menu item, and one for a text input type field. both in HTML of course. I want to test if the fields are empty, zero, whatever in that context.

I have tried to alter the code, but cannot seem to find the right code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#companyDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
        $("#companyButton").on("click", function() {
            $("#companyDialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
    // Validating Form Fields.....
    $("#companySubmit").click(function(e) {
        var comnpanyname = $("#companyname").val();
        var editcompanyscombo = $("#editcompanyscombo").val();
        if (companyname === '' || editcompanyscombo === '') {
            alert("Please fill all fields marked with an *!");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (editcompanyscombo === '0') {
            alert("Select comany to update!");
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            alert("Form Submitted Successfully.");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<div id="companyDialog" title="Edit company">
<form action="" method="post">
<@@ CompanyEditCombo @@><br>
<label>New company name:</label>
<input id="companyname" name="companyname" type="text">
<input id="companySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<input id="companyButton" type="button" value="Open Company Edit Dialog Form">
</div>
</div>
```

The fields pop up, but they do not alert if the values are zero or empty.

Answer (score 1):

So far I could see from these snippets, please replace `=== ''` and `=== '0'` by `== null`

(Double equality comparison operator does not aimed to compare the types. That is why, one should use it because `null` is type `object`. s. [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null))

Comment: Thanks, pr-olga. I tried this and it did not work. This are the whole code, not just a snipplet.